# I'm repeatedly getting the initialized value after using if statement in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just started off learning Adroid studio and coding with Java. I'm not sure why my  if statement returns a value of 0(The initialized value).
The code above the onclicklistener works fine.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thecart);
    Intent caller = getIntent();
    String item = caller.getStringExtra("choice");
    TextView disptext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carttoptext);
    disptext.setText("You selected " + item);
    EditText quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputquantity);
    Button calc= (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double price=0;
            double vquant = valueOf(quantity.getText().toString());
            String item = caller.getStringExtra("choice");
            if (item.equals("Eggs")) {
                price = vquant * 4;
            } else if (item.equals("Milk")) {
                price = vquant * 30;
            } else if (item.equals("Bread")) {
                price = vquant * 23;
            } else if (item.equals("Chips")) {
                price = vquant * 20;
            } else if (item.equals("Maggi")) {
                price = vquant * 15;
            }
            DecimalFormat formatval = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
            TextView pricetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pricetext);
            pricetext.setText("Total: " + formatval.format(price));
        }
    });
}
```

}
I'm expecting the textview beneath the edittext to give me the value vquant*(if condition value). But I'm getting the Textview as Total: 0 , which is the initializing value.

What changes should I make to the code so that I get desired output?

Answer (score 0):

check if the vquant is able to fetch the value from the quantity as a double.
ValueOf() change the data into String and you are taking that data to a double variable. It won't work. Use Double.valueOf()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Double.parseDouble(..)" instead of valueOf?